# Separate string array elements with next line \n or separator

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

I need some help with these strings. My code is:

```
String string = database.getCurrentDate();;
String[] array = string.split("[.]", 0);
String date = array[0] + "." + array[1];
String string1=database.getCurrentHour();
String[] array1=string1.split("[:]",0);
String hour=array1[0]+":"+array1[1];
String finalString=date+hour;// finalString is 28.0310:45
```

I need that `finalString` to be:

```
date
hour//on next line
example:
28.03//date
10:45//hour
```

The point is that I need the hour to be displayed on the next line, under date.
Thank you!

Comment: `date + '\n' + hour`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String finalString = date + "\n" + hour
```

Don't work if you display this?

Comment: No. I have compile error.

Comment: I adjusted the snippet to fix the compile error